# Best way to setup a deployed contract address to the frontend config

Tags: javascript, smartcontracts, truffle

I'm deploying a smart contract on a local ethereum instance using truffle and ganache.

Once I deploy the contract, I copy the address and paste if to the javascript configuration of a frontend that connects to that smart contract using web3.

Is there a better way to automate this, so my frontend config gets updated every time y redeploy the contract, rather than having to copy and paste the address?

Comment: You can use Truffle Exec https://medium.com/@timothyjcoulter/truffle-tricks-for-ethereum-development-dispelling-8-myths-first-impressions-880f66bf3320#69be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Zulhilmi's hint about using `truffle exec` I could figure out a more complete answer for this.

Inside truffle scripts you can access an object with info about the deployed instance of the Smart Contract. Including its address.

That way, I could do this script to get the address and write it to the frontend config file as part of my build process.

```js
var CryptoFreaks = artifacts.require('CryptoFreaks');

module.exports = async function() {
  
  const instance = await CryptoFreaks.deployed(); 
  console.log(instance.address);

  // Write to frontend config file here

};
```

^ That script needs to be run with `truffle exec` indeed